# Maven, exclude hamcrest dependency for junit

Tags: java, maven, junit

I excluded hamcrest dependency for junit depdendency in pom.xml.
When I compare logs upon running `"mvn package"` and  `"mvn dependency:tree"`, I do not see any difference before and after exclduing hamcrest dependency.

Here is the portion for excluding the transitive dependency.  Where can I find the difference before and after running the exclusion part?  I also looked into .m2 directory

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
       <version>${junit.version}</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
       <exclusions>
         </exclusion>
            <groupId> org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: is `<exclusions></exclusion>` a typo in question or actual mistake in the pom.xml?

Answer (score 1):

As Kiril S. stated the shown pom portion is not valid, because of the typo, which should result in an error when executing any task.

The exclusion is wrong since it does match up any dependency declared by junit.
Running `mvn dependency:tree` should show the following:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ my-app ---
[INFO] com.mycompany.app:my-app:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO]    \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
```

As you see the actual dependency of junit would be

```
<groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
<artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
```

If you fix that up in your pom the invocation of `mvn dependency:tree` will result in the expected exclusion.

```
[INFO] com.mycompany.app:my-app:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```